# Extra "Member" category after login

Tags: category, magento-1.9, login, ce-1.9.0.1

I want to have a extra, member specific category or page, after a member signed in.
So I can show products to the member that are only meant for him personally.

So I have a complete shop with al my 'public' products and a 'restricted' category or page for specific members that will only show products after login to my store.

With no login every one will see only the "public" products. After login Member-A will see an extra "personal" category or page with products meant only for him. 
The "personal" page has to be member specific so Member-B can have his own "personal" product page as well.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not trivial since you need to rewrite quite a few core classes, like the category collections.

Fortunately it already has been done. Take a look at this open source extension: [Groups Catalog 2](https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2) by Vinai Kopp